# blue screen of error Default boot device missing or boot failed ACER laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bios

i came across this issue for the first time, last night i turned off my acer laptop as usual and it went off smoothly. Today when i turned it on again then it came with an error of a black screen saying "Exiting PXE ROM-- No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" then i went to internet and checked for a solution and found to change the boot order then i first changed to "setup Default" by pressing F9 but this didn't work then i changed the periority order in BIOS and tried both HDD0 and HDD1 by keeping them on first priority one by one but this didn't work too.

So i tried again searching and someone suggested to change UEFI mode to Legacy, I did so but now came another error of blue screen that said "Default boot device missing or boot failed". Now when i changed Legacy back to UEFI then again that black screen error came. Then i checked on acer website and found another way and tried too that was turning laptop on and keep ALT pressed and tapping on F10 but this didn't work and nothing came on the screen.

As i was on hit and try i also changed the SATA mode from AHCI to RAID but this didn't work either. I reverted back to AHCI. Now when i noticed in my BIOS there isn't any model or serial number for both HDD0 and HDD1 they are set to "None".

I have checked other solutions and some of them includes checking hard drive with another computer, but don't know how to open this laptop (i'm afraid it might cause more errors) also i don't have external case for hard disk to check the hard drive by connecting it to other computer.

Another solution says boot record is corrupted and it recommends formatting the Hard disk completely and then re-install fresh Windows but how to format it? I can't access it?

Laptop Specs:

- Aspire V5-573P-6896
- Core i5-4200 1.6GHZ with turbo boost upto 2.6
- Hard disk size: 320GB
- RAM: 12GB
- Touch Screen
- Installed OS is Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This sounds increasingly like a file needed to boot your system was either corrupted or removed, and is a common issue in either botched updates, bad starts, or viruses. The only way you can actually format the drive and/or back up your files is by buying a SATA-USB adapter or some other method of connecting the drive to your PC, then doing what needs to be done there.

Comment: yup it is common sense issue but happened first time and i don't know why because no virus issue until last turned off and also that went so smoothly like always. I just want to know the reason behind it so i can avoid it in future, thanks for your reply btw